# Retrieving a belongsTo relationship data in a hasOne relationship (deep associations)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, model-associations

I'm building this CakePHP application with a `Teaser` model, each `Teaser` has one `Location`. 
Each `Location` belongs to a `Country` and a `State`.

On the index side of `Teaser` (and view) I want to display the `Country.abbr` and `State.title` of the `Location` associated with this `Teaser`

## Associations

**Teaser**

```
public $hasOne = array('Location');
```

**Location**

```
public $belongsTo = array('Teaser','Country','State');
```

**Country**

```
public $hasMany = array('Location');
```

**State**

```
public $hasMany = array('Location');
```

## What have I tried

### Default

If I do the following

```
$teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all');
```

in my `TeasersController` then it won't fetch the correct Country and State. I have seen it working and I had no problem to fetch a country title in my view through the Teaser model as follows:

```
$teaser['Location']['Country']['title'];
$teaser['Location']['State']['title'];
```

So first this worked, after working on some other stuff I noticed this stopped working (not sure if other stuff had influenced this, but I didn't touched the model. As a good programmer I started looking here.

### Containable behaviour

I've read about the Containable behaviour being amazing so I looked up on how to use it and came up with the following.

```
$this->Teaser->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

$teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Location' => array(
            'Country',
            'State'
        ),
        'User',
    ),
));
$this->set('teasers', $teasers);
```

This does not work, it gives the following error:
`Model "Location" is not associated with model "Country"`

### Recursive parameter

I've tried setting recursive to 2 (or -1 in association with the Containable Behaviour) as it was a solution before for others, but I've seen comments on how you better stick with the Containable Behaviour.

## Actual question

So, Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong here? Is the syntax wrong or am I getting these associations all mixed up?

#### Related question

Furthermore a related question on the side I've left out in the main part, but is an association between `Country` and `State` a wise idea? Our would this just complicate things even more?

Comment: empty model and persistent folder on app/tmp/Cache... It might be a problem of model caching as you said its work before...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the containable behavior on the fly, I would add the following properties to your AppModel, since using containable should be the default state, rather than the exception.

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable'); 
public $recursive = -1;
```

In case you weren't already aware, the reason people say use containable instead of recursive is that recursive will get everything all the time, even when you don't need it.  So recursive is easy to use, but it encourages bad habits.

As for your query, I don't see anything that jumps out at me as being incorrect.  I would try, as a test only, doing

```
  $this->Teaser->recursive = 2;
  $teasers = $this->Teaser->find('all');
```

Then see what it comes back with.  If it doesn't contain your associated data, you'll know there's something wrong with the associations themselves.  If it does get the associated data, then it's something with the query.

As for your related question, that's more of design question which doesn't necessarily have a right answer.

Comment: I've changed to what u suggested, even with the test. Still no luck, even deleted the model & persistent cache files, as suggest by @Fazal Rasel.  To clear some things out, I have 2 other HABTM relationship set up with my `Teaser` model. These don't have any problems and are associated with the model. `Location` does show, but it's the `Location` associations with `Country` & `State` that does not shows. Still it contains the country_id & state_id.